# Seeking combinatorial interpretation of a quantity that comes up from central hyperplane arrangements

Tags: co.combinatorics, posets, hyperplane-arrangements, mobius-inversion

Let $\mathcal A$ be a central hyperplane arrangement in $\mathbb R^d$ and let's assume that it is essential, meaning the hyperplanes in $\mathcal A$ intersect in the origin.  The intersection lattice $L(\mathcal A)$ consists of those subspaces of $\mathbb R^d$ that are intersections of hyperplanes from $\mathcal A$ (including the empty intersection which is interpreted as $\mathbb R^d$) ordered by *reverse* inclusion.  So notice that $\mathbb R^d$ is the bottom of $L(\mathcal A)$ and $\{0\}$ is the top.  Let $\mu$ be the Mobius function of $L(\mathcal A)$.

Consider the quantity $$Q_{\mathcal A}=\sum_{W\in L(\mathcal A)}|\mu (W,\{0\})|.$$

Does $Q_{\mathcal A}$ have a natural interpretation in terms of the combinatorics of the arrangement?  Note that Zaslavsky's theorem gives $$\sum_{W\in L(\mathcal A)}|\mu(\mathbb R^d,W)|$$ is the number of chambers of the arrangement, but this is, in some sense that is imprecise, a dual quantity.

I know that when $\mathcal A$ is the braid arrangement in $\mathbb R^n$, $Q_{\mathcal A}$ counts the number of necklaces of set partitions of $n$ (i.e., you look at ordered set partitions of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ up to cyclic permutations).

Comment: You mean "central," not "essential."

Comment: @RichardStanley I meant both but only so I could call the intersection of the hyperplanes 0.  Maybe my terminology is slightly off

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\Delta$ be a matroid complex, i.e., an abstract simplicial complex whose faces are the independent sets of a matroid $M$. Let $K[\Delta]$ denote the face ring (aka "Stanley-Reisner ring") of $\Delta$ over a field $K$. Let $\beta_i(K[\Delta])$ denote the Betti numbers of a minimal free resolution of $K[\Delta]$, regarded as a module (in fact, quotient ring) over $K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, where $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are the vertices of $\Delta$.  Then
$$ \beta_i(K[\Delta]) = \sum |\mu(W,\{0\})|, $$
where $W$ ranges over all flats of $M$ of corank $i$. In particular, the sum of all the Betti numbers is the sum requested. See Theorem 9 of [http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/34.pdf](http://math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/pubs/pubfiles/34.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. Let me assimilate this.

Comment: Can these betti numbers be computed from the simplicial complex?

Comment: See the above reference. For general simplicial complexes, the Betti numbers are sums of dimensions of homology groups of  restrictions $\Delta_W$ of $\Delta$ to some subset $W$ of the vertices (Theorem 4). For matroid complexes, the homology of each $\Delta_W$ vanishes except in the top dimension (this property is in fact equivalent to being a matroid complex), so the top dimensional homology is just the reduced Euler characteristic of $\Delta_W$, up to sign.

Comment: OK. Thanks.  I remember reading about this once long ago in connection with Leray numbers.  Ok. I'll try to read the paper.  Thanks for your answer.